# ifstream, Getline returns a memory address

Tags: c++, string, file, pointers

i have the following code:

```
std::ifstream report( fileToRead );
cout << "leyendo archivo: " << fileToRead << endl;
std::string line;
cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
report.close();
```

But cout give the following result: 0x28fe64 What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Base on this reference, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/.

The `getline` function return reference to an `ifstream` object, that is the reason you get an address printed.

You need `cout << line;` to print out the content read.

**I also failed to repeat your bug, which version of g++ and OS you are using?** My g++ as following:

> Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 Thread model: posix

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char * fileToRead= "a.txt";
    std::ifstream report( fileToRead );
    cout << report << endl;

    cout << "leyendo archivo: " << fileToRead << endl;
    std::string line;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    cout << std::getline(report,line) << endl;
    report.close();
}
```

The result I got is:

```
1
leyendo archivo: a.txt
1
1
1
0
0
0
```

It seems that the ifstream is converted to boolean variable indicating whether there are any file operation error with the ifstream. The final three zero is due to there is no more lines to read.

Comment: Actually, the reason it prints an address is the conversion from `ifstream` to `void *` that is [which happens to return `this` or `NULL` on failure, I believe]

Comment: You have been very helpful, I have fixed the code and worked! But I don't know the reason why getline doesn't read from my file, it shows a 'code' \n 'code' I write this code based in comments on stackoverflow and it is supossed work.

Comment: Which comments or post you are following? What is the file you are reading? 'code' is the string output to the console?